# como puedo llamar una funcion en un if en vue js

Tags: vue.js

quiero llamar una función contadora dentro de un if de vue quisiera saber como puedo hacerlo
ya que quiero que se valla acumulando cada vez que se cumpla la condición 
y todo lo estoy trabajando con vue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
var noticias new vuew(
  { el: '#app', 
    data { contador: 1}, 
    methods: { sumarUno: function(){ 
                       this.contador++  
                   }  
             }  
});
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

```
<div v-if="contador===0"> <div class="carousel-item active" > <img 
class="d-block w-100" src="<?= base_url() ?>{{f.Foto}}" alt="First 
slide"/> </div> <div v-else"> <div class="carousel-item" > <img class="d- 
block w-100" src="<?= base_url() ?>{{f.Foto}}" alt="First slide"/> </div>
```

Comment: y cual es la condicion que deseas que se cumnpla?

Comment: <div v-if="contador===0">

                            <div class="carousel-item  active"  >
                              <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?= base_url() ?>{{f.Foto}}" alt="First slide"/>
                              
                            </div>

                            <div v-else">
                            <div class="carousel-item"  >
                              <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?= base_url() ?>{{f.Foto}}" alt="First slide"/>
                              
                            </div>

Comment: esa es la consulta es que estoy haciendo un carrusel y tengo que poner la primera imagen activa y las otras no

Comment: si es conteo local solo agrega esto v-on:click="contador+= 1" pero si lo quieres guardar en la base de datos debes hacerlo por ajax.

Comment: si entiendo el detalle es que yo lo estoy haciendo dentro de un for y si es conteo local

Comment: Cristian, con Vue se puede añadir o quitar una clase según una condición. No es necesario que el div se repita. [Docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Comment: Veo muchos errores en el código que compartes y por lo que dices que quieres hacer, dar más contexto probablemente daría una mejor solución. Pero por ejemplo, tu `v-else` está dentro de el div que tiene `v-if`. Estos deben estar a la misma altura, no uno dentro del otro.

Comment: ```<div id="app">
  <div v-if="contador===0">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="First slide" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div v-else>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="" alt="First slide" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>```